# How can I limit the number of rows in data grid after data grid gets created?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am creating a data grid and calling it as a popup from one screen , now the data provider(array collection) is a public property which is being provided by the screen which calls the popup , now I want to limit the row Count as data provider.length + 2.
Please tell me how can I do this , or in which method i can do this as my data grid is getting created first so I want to limit row size after its creation.

Answer (score -1):

Bind the DataGrid row count property to dataProvider.length + 2:

```
rowCount = "{dataProvider.length + 2}"
```

This is for mx DataGrid. If you use spark DataGrid,
use "requestedRowCount" instead of "rowCount"

Comment: if you add something to the dataProvider then the rowCount will change because it is binded.

Comment: I thought that was the OP intent. If he doesn't want to have the update, then set the rowCount in the "initialize" property.